# Usar um método de uma classe a partir de uma string concatenada

Tags: python, string

Olá, sou novato em Pyhon...

tenho uma classe Chamada Carro, e nela tenho um método chamado nome que me retorna o nome do meu objeto. Ex.: carro_1.nome() = retorna o nome do carro.

Tenho os objetos, carro_1, carro_2, carro_3...

Executando carro_1.nome() recebo o nome do carro.

tenho uma lista com preços de todos os carros, em ordem, preço na posição 1 é referente ao carro_1, posição 2 é referente ao carro_2 etc

Encontrei o menor preço da minha lista e sua posição.

com isso concatenei 'carro_' + 'posição + 1 '
Ex.: o menor preço esta na posição 0
concatenei: 'carro_' + '1', obtive 'carro_1'

só que estou com dificuldades de acessar o método nome() referente à string que obtive.

Comment: Sim, mas isso não precisa ser feito. Há maneiras melhores de gerenciar esse acesso dinâmico à funções de objetos. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um exemplo para entendermos melhor o que está tentando fazer?

Comment: Editei, por favor veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: E como é gerada essa lista de preços? Por que esse preço não faz parte do próprio objeto carro?

Comment: o preço é gerado pelo usuário, pois tem algumas variáveis na geração dos preços.. Mas saberia uma forma de eu acessar o objeto da maneira q estou fazendo, ou um modo semelhante.

Comment: Usar uma string para chamar um objeto de mesmo nome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando programamos em orientação a objeto, utilizamos **Getters** e **Setters** para obtenção de valores dentro de uma variável e encapsulamento dos dados.... Recomendo estudar programação orientada a objeto para entender o *modus operandi* desse paradigma.

Exemplo de propiedade com get e set:

```
class NaoSei:

   def __init__(self, algo):
        self._algo = algo

   @property  # Getter
   def algo(self):
       return self._algo

   @algo.setter  # Setter
   def algo(self, value):
       self._algo = value
```

E com isso você irá poder chamar a sua propiedade da forma correta:

```
c = NaoSei('teste')
print(c.algo)
```

Dessa forma o seu código irá estar seguindo corretamente o paradigma de orientação a objeto, irá encapsular a sua classe, e irá facilitar a manutenção/implementação do código.

Quer limitar para apenas a classe poder manipular a propiedade? Simples! remova o setter.
Precisa fazer um calculo ao settar a propiedade? É só implementar no setter.

Exemplo:

```
   @algo.setter  # Setter
   def algo(self, value):
       value = 'outro ' + value
       self._algo = value
```

Daí é só fazer isso para seta-lo:

```
c = NaoSei('teste')
print(c.algo)
>teste
c.algo = 'teste'
print(c.algo)
>outro teste
```